# If $a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ix^i = b_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_ix^i$, show that $a_0 = b_0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now. My prof didn't really go over it as he was explaining its implications in another part of the question, but I can't really figure out this particular equality in and of itself.

Comment: The equality implicitly means that it is equal for all $x$. Then choose $x=0$ and see what happen.

Comment: More generally, the only way for this relation to be true for all $x$ is for all the coefficients to match term-by-term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $x^0 = 1$ so $a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ix^i = \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_ix^i$.

Also note that $P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_ix^i - \sum_{i=0}^{n} b_ix^i = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (a_i-b_i)x^i$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $x$ so it has at most $n$ real roots. If it has more than $n$ roots, in particular if $P(x)=0$ for $\forall x$, then it follows that $P \equiv 0$ is the identical zero polynomial, which means $a_i = b_i$ for $0 \le i \le n$.

Answer (score 0):

If the polynomials are the same they have the same y intercept.